# VSCode Python Running ommand Error: /bin/sh: python: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I think I'm having path related issues on VSCode.

I completely removed and reinstalled reinstalled the OS, I have Monterey 12.3.1

I installed Python using brew:

```
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.9.12

➜  ~ which python3    
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

However I have issues normally running my code on the mac.
I can run from the terminal using

```
➜  test Python3 test.py
Hello World!
```

but if I try to run using right-clic -> run, I get:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/user/Desktop/test/test.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found
```

but if I clic on 'Run & Debug' in the left panel I get:

```
➜  test  /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 56623 -- /Users/user/Desktop/test/test.py 
Hello World!
```

Weirdly, if I try to run the program with the run button from the touchbar it works:

```
➜  test  cd /Users/hugo/Desktop/test ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/hugo/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 56632 -- /Users/hug
o/Desktop/test/test.py 
Hello World!
```

Could this problem be related to Apple removing Python2 from macOS in Monterey ?

I noticed that the command "python" wasn't working anymore in my terminal so think it might be related to that, but I'm not sure how to solve that in vscode without messing up paths

Comment: same issue. vscode 1.66.2

Answer (score 13):

The issue is with Code Runner. But it's an easy fix. Open Code runner's Executor map settings.json --> find "python" and you'll notice that it says something like "python" == "python -u" --> change this to "python" == "python3" and the code should be running with the shortcuts in the Output window.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you!! This answer is the only one that fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you installed python using homebrew, it should be in (by default)

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Your issue is actually with the Code Runner. Try to click `Run Python File` on the top right side of vscode.

[image]

Your code will be running well

**Another information**

```
macOS since version 10.8 comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed by Apple .
```

Information about this [https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#:~:text=5.1.-,Getting%20and%20Installing%20MacPython,www.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#:%7E:text=5.1.-,Getting%20and%20Installing%20MacPython,www.python.org)).

So if you run

```
➜  ~ which python3
```

Even if you haven't installed python. By default, show to directory

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are very useful！

And there is another way：

1. open **Code -> Preferences -> Settings** or press `command` + `，`
2. search `Run In Terminal`
3. Select it!

Answer (score 1):

Much more easy is create a symbolic link via command line (linux, macos).
`ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python`

Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

click on extension in vscode and type "code runner". select the setting on the code runner and click on  extension settings and on edit in settings.json change as python3 instead of python. it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).